# Errno::EACCES in PicturesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, carrierwave

I'm using the carrierwave-dropbox gem and using both win 10 & mac os x with my rails app but on windows (and not Mac) I get this error when trying to upload (the upload occurs, it doesn't write to the app db on localhost).

```
Errno::EACCES in PicturesController#create
Permission denied @ unlink_internal C:/Users/name/apps/dropbox/public/uploads/tmp/1448853449-5268-0532/IMG_7871.JPG
```

I've read articles about permissions and I have tried changing those but with no success - is there anything else recommended I should try?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing the permission of the `uploads` directory this way?:

```
chmod -R 666 C:/Users/name/apps/dropbox/public/uploads 
chmod -R 666 C:/Users/name/apps/dropbox/public/uploads/tmp
```

If not, try it. Because the issue is related to the permission of the files inside the `uploads` directory.

Comment: Yes, made no difference - the app still gets the same error at the same point (after trying to upload). Again it doesn't write to the db and does upload to dropbox. Also it does write to the directory (it saves an image in the public tmp folder) so it is writing to the directory.....????

Comment: can you try `chmod -R 777` instead? just want to test.

Comment: Can you also check if it really changed the permission of the files inside the /tmp and /uploads folders? Get some help on this from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx